# replacing a word in a string based on the content of the file in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file with the following line - `a boy is drinking water`. say i call this file A.txt

My objective is to replace the word `water`  with anything the user gives as input in A.txt.
and retaining the other stuff intact.
If A.txt is changed to `a boy is drinking juice` and is passed A.txt as parameter to the Python script, I want the output to be `a boy is drinking juice`.

How can we replace only that particular letter in a string.

Comment: What if the line is "a boy is eating watermelon"?  Do you want that to become "a boy is eating juicemelon"?

Answer (score 4):

Open the file,and retrieve contents.
To replace a certain string in a word use `textFromFile.replace('oldtext','newtext')`
Save contents to file.

Comment: Good solution but can you change your variable name to `text` or something because `str.replace` doesn't work like that

Answer (score -1):

use this code

```
namespace string_replace
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"a.txt");
        //read the text to replace
        text.Replace("water","user_string");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"A.txt", text);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Considering that the OP just came here and asked for people to code his program for him, I don't mind if it's not python haha.